# Need help understanding composition and class functions in c++

Tags: c++

I'm just beginning to study c++ and need help understanding what is going on between these classes and functions. If classA has-a classB, if I use a setter for class B, through class A, it makes no change.

If I use the classB setter directly, it works fine. I have also figured out that I can make the functions work if I use pointers, but what I am looking for an understanding of why this doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>

ClassA
{
private:
    ClassB test;
public:
    ClassB getTest(){return test;}
};

ClassB
{
private:
    int a = 10;
public:
    int getA(){return a;}
    void setA(int b){a += b;}
};

int main()
{
    ClassA myClass;
    myClass.getTest().setA(20);
    std::cout << myClass.getTest().getA(); // Will return 10 still
}
```

My thought was this would modify int a in test to 30, but it does not and int a remains 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClassB getTest(){return test;}
```

This returns a **copy** of `test`. You modify the copy, instead of the member `test` itself. So later you observe no change in `test`.

To allow the user to modify it, you need to return by **reference**:

```
ClassB& getTest(){return test;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're going to love this. C++ isn't Java. Your access method on ClassA is returning a COPY of your ClassB object, not some sort of reference to it. It's an entirely different ClassB object, so if you fiddle with it, you're not fiddling with the one from A anymore.

You need your access method to look like this:

```
ClassB & getTest(){return test;}
```

Note that the & says "a reference". This is under the hood a pointer, but you get to use dot notation instead of arrow notation.

After that, your code as written should work. But note if you call myClass.getTest() and then do manipulations, it would look like:

```
ClassB & myClassB = myClass.getTest();
myClassB.setA(20);
```

Now, as a warning, this code compiles:

```
ClassB myClassB = myClass.getTest();
myClassB.setA(20);
```

And what this code says is, "myClass -- give me a reference to your ClassB object. But then I'm going to construct a new ClassB object and copy yours into it." In other words, it works the same way as if getTest() was not returning a reference.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense as to why I could make it work returning a pointer and using pointer notation instead. I am coming from Java too.

Comment: I've been programming since the 70s, but I recognized the Java influences in your example. C and C++ get you a LOT closer to the hardware. You're dealing with real pointers, and you can do pointer arithmetic. In the past, I have found it useful to actually diagram out memory use, with slots holding pointers and what not. I've never really done that with Java. You don't really think about pointers so much. So C++ is really cool, but it also requires you to think like a computer. That's the most valuable thing to learn if you want to program C/C++.